# How to generate hexagon polygons with coordinates of the center point in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have given a database with coordinates and want to use these coordinates as the center points for hexagon polygons. PostGIS provides this convenient function: [ST_Hexagon](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_Hexagon.html)

The example from the reference works as expected:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID(ST_Hexagon(1.0, 0, 0), 3857));

POLYGON((-1 0,-0.5
     -0.866025403784439,0.5
     -0.866025403784439,1
     0,0.5
     0.866025403784439,-0.5
     0.866025403784439,-1 0))
```

However, when I use my coordinates with ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (EPSG:25832) and an edge length of 100m:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID(ST_Hexagon(100.0, 5794575, 640800), 25832));
```

My results are totally wrong:

```
POLYGON((869186150 110989902.35155405,
         869186200 110989815.74901368,
         869186300 110989815.74901368,
         869186350 110989902.35155405,
         869186300 110989988.95409442,
         869186200 110989988.95409442,
         869186150 110989902.35155405))
```

The expected results should be around these values:

```
5794632.380551 640799.725314
5794604.912737 640849.167379
5794546.200284 640849.510727
5794517.359079 640799.381966
5794546.88698 640749.596553
5794602.852651 640748.909858
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The function signature is `ST_Hexagon(float8 size, integer cell_i, integer cell_j, geometry origin);`

The coordinates are in cell space, not in geographic space. That is, the 1st hexagon has cell coordinates `0;0`, its neighbor `0;1` etc, regardless of the hexagon size.

What you can do is to keep the asking for the hexagon `0;0`, but to move the grid origin to your location

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(
  ST_SetSRID(
    ST_Hexagon(100.0, 0,0, st_makepoint(5794575, 640800)),
  25832));
                                   
----------
 POLYGON((5794475 640800,
5794525 640713.3974596215,
5794625 640713.3974596215,
5794675 640800,
5794625 640886.6025403785,
5794525 640886.6025403785,
5794475 640800))
```